# How to monitor changes to a mutable object?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a few computationally expensive properties on some classes. These properties do not change as long as the mutable/underlying attributes do not change. Is there a way to store the expensive property, and only re-calculate it if a change has been made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the other variables in your property method and use them as part of a cache key:

```
class CachedProperties(object):
    @property
    def expensiveValue(self):
        cacheKey = (self.var1, self.var2)
        if cacheKey in self._expensiveValueCache:
            return self._expensiveValueCache[cacheKey]

        # No cached value available, calculate it now
        res = self._expensiveValueCache[cacheKey] = calculation(self.var1, self.var2)
        return res
```

Now you defer calculation until you actually need the expensive value *and* var1 or var2 have changed.

Comment: Remember to evict from cache too.

Comment: @Deestan: that complicates the code quite a lot, and outside the scope of this answer; only needed if var1 and var2 are changing a lot during the lifetime of the program *and* expensiveValue is retrieved a lot.

Comment: Just `self._expensiveValueCache = {}` before recalculation would be much better than nothing.

Comment: @Deestan: Would it? What if the (val1, val2) combo has a small range and the same combinations come up again and again in the lifetime of the app? Without more detail as to what the use cases are you cannot make any such statements.

Comment: Yes it might not be the *best* solution - which as you say we can't guess at before more details, **but** evicting too often is infinitely better than never evicting.

Comment: @Deestan: No, I can't say I agree. Evicting a really expensive calculation who's resulting value is small in terms of memory should be retained as much as possible, for example.

Comment: Well, the problem has been addressed and discussed at least. Agreeing on something doesn't make sense anyway, as we don't know the system details. :-) We're both erring on the side of caution, but with assumptions based on different previous experience.  For example, I'm used to working with systems which have to run under heavy use for several months without manual interference or monitoring.

Comment: I suppose you could make a custom dictionary that ranked "usefulness of cached value", perhaps by number of times the key is accessed. Then put an upper limit on the cache size so that it would purge cached values "intelligently". Would that be a sensible option?

Comment: @cammil: sure; you can implement a variety of cache purging strategies; FIFO, most accessed, etc.